# Install error when "npx @teambit/bvm install" bit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, bit

There is an error when I trying to install bit.

npx @teambit/bvm install
request to https://bvm.bit.dev/bit/index.json failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND proxy.example.com
FetchError: request to https://bvm.bit.dev/bit/index.json failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND proxy.example.com
at ClientRequest. (C:\Users\bill\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@teambit\bvm\node_modules@teambit\bvm.list\node_modules\node-fetch\lib\index.js:1491:11)
at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:513:28)
at onerror (C:\Users\bill\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@teambit\bvm\node_modules\agent-base\dist\src\index.js:117:21)
at callbackError (C:\Users\bill\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@teambit\bvm\node_modules\agent-base\dist\src\index.js:136:17)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

node v18.15.0
npm 8.11.0
any helps would be pleasure!

I have tried set proxy to null, registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/ and @bit:registry=https://node.bit.cloud in .npmrc